# Update Bounce Category and SubCategory in CRM through Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way to update CRM Objects with the Bounce SubCategory?

I have a JB that always after a send i create a Task Activity to record in CRM for the service people. I update after 3 days if the email send was bounce, opened or clicked with Engagement Split, but i thinking if we have the option to put the Bounce Subcategory and Category (Data View) directly through Journey Builder.

[image]

Comment: There is not a way to do this in JB, yo could use the _bounce data view and an ssjs activity leveraging the Salesforce ampscript functions

Comment: You could query the _Bounce data view and use the output data extension as the entry event for a Journey that updates CRM or add this output data extension to your contact model and use data binding in your Salesforce Task Activity to pull the Bounce Categorisation into fields in the Task.